# Edit a UITextView in a ScrollView swift

Tags: swift, textview, scrollview, edit

I've been looking for an answer for a while to this basic problem but can't find anything to solve it. 
I have a UITextView in a UIScrollVIew, but I can't edit the text of my textView, it means when I run the project and click on the textView the keyboard does not show up and I can't edit the text.
I tried different configuration but it seems that none works.
My code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var imageView2: UIImageView!
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var textView = UITextView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView2 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.png"))

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView2.bounds.size
    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.isExclusiveTouch = true
    scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView2)


    textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:24,y: 100,width: 340,height: 290))
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 1.00, blue: 0.00, alpha: 1.00)
    textView.text = "bla bla bla"
    imageView2.addSubview(textView)
```

I will probably be ashamed when I will get the answer.. I guess it's something easy but can't seem to find it. I enabled the user to interact, I thought it would be enough, which is not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: a quick try in playground]

you need to add textview in imageview before adding it into scroll view.

Comment: I applied your code, declaring textview in imageview2 before adding the scroll view, I run, but if i click on the text I can't edit it.

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to achieve by adding textview in imageview

Comment: place last line above 2nd last line and then check

Comment: Understood ! thank you ! I added the textview (addSubview) after I added imageView2.
Also, to enable editing of the textView, I added :

    imageView2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true